# Javascript function doesn't run

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a java-script function that doesn't want to run. The weird thing is that other functions in the code run fine. The function I'm having trouble with is addMarkers(). I even went so far as to copy the addMarker() function and then change the name. When I call addMarker() it runs perfectly but when I call addMarkers() it doesn't work at all despite being the same thing and being right next to the other one.

What am I missing?

```
var markers = [];

var map;
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 2,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

// Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearOverlays() {
    setAllMap(null);
}

// Shows any overlays currently in the array.
function showOverlays() {
    setAllMap(map);
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteOverlays() {
    clearOverlays();
    markers = [];
}

function resetMap() {
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0));
    map.setZoom(2);

    deleteOverlays();
}


function addMarker(lat, lng) {

    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map : map,
        draggable : false,
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
}


function addMarkers(lat, lng) {

    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map : map,
        draggable : false,
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

HTML document that runs the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps API Testing</title>
    <!--meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120"-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #B0C4DE;
      }
      #map-canvas{
        height:1020px;
        width:1040px;
        border: 5px black solid;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        left: 5px;
      }
      form{
        position:relative;
        left: 20px;
        top: 15px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?Key={AIzaSyBLp3nQtaofsWbtwTH4rwgOoPJ8fARnUPA}&sensor=false"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="maps.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="addMarkers(0,0)">

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <form name="form">
        <input type="button" value="Reset Map" onclick="resetMap();" />

        <br />
        Lat: <input type="number" name="lat"/>
        Lng: <input type="number" name="lng" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Drop Icon" onclick="addMarker(form.lat.value, form.lng.value);" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where/how are you calling the function(s)? Do you have an element with ID `addMarkers`? Having a global function with the same name as an element's ID might not work.

Comment: I have an html page that calls it. Right now the body just has an onload that calls the function. It works for the other functions so it must be a problem here. I can post the html if you think it'd be helpful

Comment: remove addMarker and then check it..also try to have aler('i am here'); only inside it and check either it is being call or not?

Comment: You could post the *relevant* part of the HTML. Also [read this article](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to learn how to **debug** JavaScript.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: I removed addmarker() same problem

Comment: @nnnnnn How do I check? I'm using firefox

Comment: Read the article I linked to in my comment.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, that was very informative. Firebug is reporting that it's not defined. But I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script, as it is, works for me(sometimes).

The issue: you have two functions that will be called onload(`addMarkers` and `initialize`).

But `addMarkers` will only run successfully when it will be called **after** `initialize`(otherwise `map` will be undefined).

As you don't have any control over the execution-order of both functions, you better move the call of `addMarkers` to the end of `initialize`.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you so much, this makes everything so much clearer.